# move in direction of rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, unity3d-2dtools

I want to click on an area of the screen, have a ship rotate to that direction while accelerating in the direction the ship is facing...I got the rotation working but I can't seem to figure out how to apply force in the direction the ship is facing:

My code sends the ship toward where I *eventually* want it to go, not where it's currently facing:

```
Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;

    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")) {
        Vector3 moveToward = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        moveDirection = moveToward - currentPosition;
        moveDirection.z = 0; 
        moveDirection.Normalize();
    }      

    float targetAngle = Mathf.moveDirection(vector.y, moveDirection.x);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, 
                         Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, targetAngle), 
                                          rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    Vector2 direction;
    direction.x = Mathf.Cos((targetAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
    direction.y = Mathf.Sin((targetAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
    direction.Normalize();

    velocity.x = direction.x * moveSpeed;
    velocity.y = direction.y * moveSpeed;         
    rigidbody2D.velocity = velocity;
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually works in this kind of situations where you are able to make the rotation:

```
Vector2 direction = transform.forward;
rigidbody2D.velocity = direction * moveSpeed;
```

Without knowing your scene layout it is hard to tell for sure.

If that is moving the ship opposite way use `- transform.forward` or if the ship is moving side ways use `transform.right`.